# ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver, how to fix it

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

it gives exception of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

```
int row=0;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MSDB");
        stmt=Con.createStatement();
        String sql="select c_name from candidates";
        RS=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(RS.next())
        {
            String name=RS.getString("c_name");
            c1.addItem(name);
            row++;
        }
       }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + ex);ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: Is the JAR containing said class on your build path?

Comment: JDBC-ODBC Bridge was removed in Java8. See [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/Lance/entry/removal_of_the_jdbc_odbc).

Comment: If you *are* using Java 8 and need to manipulate an Access database then you might be interested in the related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

Sun's and Oracle's [official positions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) have long been that --

> the [JVM-bundled] JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution [...] Oracle [was Sun] does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

However, my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), has produced enterprise-grade commercial Type 1 Bridges between JDBC and ODBC since JVM 1.0, and these are fully compatible with the current JVM 1.8.  You can learn more here --

- [Single-Tier JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://www.openlinksw.com/c/9C2VUIUG) -- a JDBC driver for ODBC data sources
- [Single-Tier ODBC-JDBC Bridge Driver](http://www.openlinksw.com/c/9C2G6JJA) -- an ODBC driver for JDBC data sources